# Adding elements to an array inside of JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    people: []
}
```

My Goal at the moment is to simply add elements to the array of people. But in the end I also would like to be able to remove the elements again.

I have tried something like:

```
<?

    $file = "test.json";
    $json = file_get_contents($file);
    $get = json_decode($json);

    array_push($get->people, $_GET['person']);

    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($get));

?>
```

However, this does not work. I'm pretty sure there is an easier solution for this. Thanks for any help.

Comment: how does this not work?

Comment: The `{ people...}` is not a valid JSON. It's a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

You have [invalid JSON](http://jsonlint.com). Keys must be [quoted](http://json.org).

```
{"people": []}
```

Otherwise, your code should work. Although I would recommend [not using PHP short open tags](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/) and [filtering user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: Well that embarrassing. Ha, I hate stupid mistakes like that. Thanks though.